# Continue is not working in for loop with if statements ('continue' not properly in loop)

Tags: python, spyder

New to coding and cant figure out why continue wont work in my for loop. After the print statements, I want to start the loop over again from the top. If anyone could let me know what im doing wrong that would be great. I am not allowed to share the cse231_random file sorry if this makes it so you cant run it.

```
import string
import random
import time
from cse231_random import randint
ALPHABET_EASY = string.ascii_letters 
ALPHABET = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation


easy_str = ""
length=random.randint(3, 5)
for i in range(length):
   index=randint(0, len(ALPHABET_EASY))
   easy_str += ALPHABET_EASY[index]
print(easy_str)
start= time.time()
easy_input=input("\nEnter this string:")
stop= time.time()
easy_input=easy_input.replace(" ", "")
easy_input=easy_input
if stop-start>10:
 print("Oops! Too much time.")
 continue
elif easy_input.lower()==easy_str.lower():
 print("Good job! You spent {} of 10 seconds entering string [{}][{}]".format(stop-start,easy_str,easy_input))
 continue
elif easy_input.lower()!=easy_str.lower():
 print("Incorrect.")
 continue
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? Because if so, the `continue`s aren't even in your loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the whole body be in indented?

```
for i in range(length):
    index=randint(0, len(ALPHABET_EASY))
    easy_str += ALPHABET_EASY[index]
    print(easy_str)
    start= time.time()
    easy_input=input("\nEnter this string:")
    stop= time.time()
    easy_input=easy_input.replace(" ", "")
    easy_input=easy_input
    if stop-start>10:
        print("Oops! Too much time.")
        continue
    elif easy_input.lower()==easy_str.lower():
        print("Good job! You spent {} of 10 seconds entering string [{}][{}]".format(stop-   start,easy_str,easy_input))
        continue
    elif easy_input.lower()!=easy_str.lower():
        print("Incorrect.")
        continue
```